Missing 'Normals' in Data
The tab of Normals/auto smooth is missing. The tutorial I was following and other videos have it in between Attributes and Texture Space.


The Normals > Auto Smooth panel doesn't exist anymore since 4.1, you need to either:

Right click in Object mode and choose Shade Smooth by Angle, which will create Mark Sharp on the edges, depending on the Angle chosen in the Operator Box:



Or right click in Object mode and choose Shade Smooth then give your object a Normals > Smooth by Angle modifier:


